# how to solve postback issue file upload control's path does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

I am uploading files using asp.net fileupload control , whenever postback occurs due to other field's on the page, selected path in file upload control lost. I'm using multiple file upload control on page for diff. Purpose how to solve this problem? Please help with simple & suitable example dear.

```
string file = Path.GetFileName(UploadSalesServiceCopy.PostedFile.FileName);
string filepath2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerMapImgPath"].ToString();//.......local drive path via web config
string subPath = filepath2 + file;
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));
if (!IsExists)
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));

if (UploadSalesServiceCopy.HasFile)
{
    //UploadSalesServiceCopy.SaveAs(subPath);//PHYSICAL path
    UploadSalesServiceCopy.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(subPath));//server path             
}
else
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "javascript", "alert('No File Selected.')", true);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify where these codes lives?

Answer (score 0):

While clicking on Upload button ...
Your page redirect to Page_load event first , where you set page values .
For that in

```
page_load(..)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      ..setpagevalues();
   }
}
```

That main reson...you are getting null path.... 
Try it..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net File upload control with update panel.Then the problem is
File upload control is not compatible with partial post back.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fpTest1" runat="server" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="fpTest2" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnActions" runat="server" Text="Other Actions" >
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" OnClick="test_Click" Text="Upload File" />
```

You can see that when you click other actions button file upload will have the values.

Put the Post back controls inside the Update Panel and have the file upload controls out 
of the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use fileupload with **updatepanel** and also put  **ViewStateMode="Enabled"** to fileupload.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"/>
 </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```